# Soft bremsstrahlung classical computation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus

On page 177 in Peskin & Schroeder there is a derivation I have a hard time with. They write the current for a charge at rest as  $$j^\mu = (1,0)^\mu e  \delta(x). $$ I don't understand what the four vector $(1,0)^\mu$ represents. Why is time=1?

Comment: For a particle the current would be $j^\mu=e u^\mu \delta(\vec x - \vec x_p(t))$ where $\vec x_p(t)$ is the particle position and $u^\mu = (dt/d\tau,d\vec x_p/d\tau) = (\gamma_p, \gamma_p \vec v_p)$, for a particle at rest you would have $\vec v_p = 0$ and $\gamma_p=1$, I thank the $\mu$ on $(1,0)^\mu$ is redundant, but, anyways, it just says that you have $\vec v_p=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time-component (0th component) of the 4-current represents charge.  The spatial components represent the 3-vector current.

Comment: Of course... I was thinking so much on position I thought.... Thanks brother.